# How to rewrite url to other file, only if index.php file does not exists

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following file structure for a few domains:

```
/index.php [optional. for some domains no index.php file]
/content.php [always present]
```

If the user requested an URL like `example.com` or `example.com/`, I want to check if `index.php` exists on the server and send him to `index.php`. But if `index.php` does not exist on the server I should send him to `content.php`.
Also if the requested URL is like `example.com/test` or `example.com/test/test2`, send him to `content.php`.

I've written something like this in `.htaccess`, but it doesn't check if `index.php` is present.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([^.]+)?$ content.php?category=$1&slug=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)?$ content.php?category=$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^*$ content.php [L]
```

How should I modify the above code to check for the existence of `index.php`? 
Also any suggestions to optimize that code?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you add content.php to the [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive? E.g.

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php content.php
</IfModule>
```

I don't think it's possible to check that a file exists in a rewrite rule.